# Could not compare integer and float values when used with gte in laravel form request validation

Tags: php, laravel

I have two attributes lower and upper and I am using like below in form request class

```
class MeasurementRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'id'                => 'required',
            'lower'             => 'numeric',
            'upper' .           => 'numeric|gte:lower'
        ];
    }
}
```

when I pass lower as 1, and upper as 4.2 it throws error saying

```
"The upper must be greater than or equal 1."
```

What is the issue here as upper is greater than lower. I see some problem with types. But not sure why. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is isodate? Without isodate, it passes for me with `lower => 1, upper => 4.2`

Comment: @senty Aah sorry. Typo I have corrected it

Comment: If it passes may I know which version of laravel? I use 5.8.36

Comment: I tested in Tinkerwell - https://web.tinkerwell.app/#/snippets/a240f919-06fb-4658-9b36-c41b56c78e73

Comment: @senty but for some reasons it is not working here